# "This function has a return type of 'Widget', but doesn't end with a return statement."

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder(
    stream: slides,
    initialData: [],
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snap) {
      List slideList = snap.data.toList();
      return PageView.builder(
          controller: ctrl,
          itemCount: slideList.length + 1,
          itemBuilder: (context, int currentIdx){
            if (currentIdx == 0) {
              return _buildTagPage();
            }
            else if (slideList.length >= currentIdx){
              bool active = currentIdx == currentPage;
              return _buildStoryPage(slideList[currentIdx - 1], active);
            }
          }
      );
    },
  );
}
```

This is an excerpt from a clone of the Reflectly app and I am getting an error in `(context, int currentIdx) {`.

I assume I have to add a return statement somewhere, but do not know where to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the `if`-`else if` combination is not **exhaustive**, which means that there could be cases, where neither of the conditions is fulfilled and thus neither of the code blocks is executed.

However, the [`itemBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IndexedWidgetBuilder.html) specifies that a `Widget` needs to be returned from the callback. Hence, you see the error.

To resolve it, you can either add an `else` statement to make the `if`-`else` combination exhaustive and return from both, or you can just add a `return` at the end, which will always be reached if the nothing was returned before;

```
    controller: ctrl,
    itemCount: slideList.length + 1,
    itemBuilder: (context, int currentIdx){
      if (currentIdx == 0) {
        return _buildTagPage();
      } else if (slideList.length >= currentIdx) {
        bool active = currentIdx == currentPage;
        return _buildStoryPage(slideList[currentIdx - 1], active);
      }

      return Text('No slide availabe.');
    }
);
```

As you can see, I added a return statement at the end, which will display a message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add return statement after two if statements, in case they're both false:

```dart
            itemBuilder: (context, int currentIdx){
              if (currentIdx == 0) {
                return _buildTagPage();
              } 
              else if (slideList.length >= currentIdx){
                bool active = currentIdx == currentPage;
                return _buildStoryPage(slideList[currentIdx - 1], active);
              }

              return [some_widget]; // <---- here
            }
```

Comment: Right. Depending on your use case, you might be able to just return Container